# Fluctuations of gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I'm studying about Neural network and I have some questions about the theory of Gradient descent.

1. why is the fluctuation(slope) of Batch gradient descent less than the fluctuation(slope) of SGD.
   [image]
2. Why SGD avoid local minima better Batch gradient descent.
3. Batch Gradient survey all data then come updates. What is its meaning?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is related to the compromise between exploitation and exploration.

1. Gradient Descend uses all the data to update the weights which implies a better update. In neural networks Batch Gradient Descend is used because the original is not applicable to practice. Instead Stochastic Gradient Descend only uses a single example and that adds noise. **With BGD and GD you exploit more data.**
2. With SGD you can avoid minimum locations because by using a single example you benefit the exploration and you can come up with other solutions that with BGD you could not, that implies noise. **SGD you explore more.**
3. BGD, takes a dataset and breaks it into N chunks where each chunk has B samples (B is the batch_size). That forces you to go through all the data in the dataset.